# Windbg "Processes and Threads" window doesn't change context when kernel debugging

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg

My "Processes and Threads" window is stuck on `000:f0f0f0f0 ntkrnlpa.exe`.

I tried changing the context in various ways, none of which affected the window.

My actions:

```
kd> !process 0 0 notepad.exe
PROCESS 821ff378  SessionId: 0  Cid: 0358    Peb: 7ffd7000  ParentCid: 05e0
    DirBase: 090801a0  ObjectTable: e18fb7b8  HandleCount: 132.
    Image: notepad.exe

kd> .process /i 821ff378
You need to continue execution (press 'g' <enter>) for the context
to be switched. When the debugger breaks in again, you will be in
the new process context.
kd> g
Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
nt!RtlpBreakWithStatusInstruction:
80527bdc cc              int     3
```

I'd expect the "Processes and Threads" window to show me now `notepad.exe` with its threads.
Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Does `.process /p /r 821ff378` help at all?

Comment: Nop. does not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

[From `windbg` help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553437%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The Processes and Threads window displays a list of all processes that are currently being debugged. The threads in the process appear under each process. If the debugger is attached to multiple systems, the systems are shown at the top level of the tree, with the processes subordinate to them, and the threads subordinate to the processes.

So the `Processes and threads` window shows only the processes/threads that are being debugged or debugger attached to, which is it showing when you are attached to kernel.

Even if you change the process context in debugger, it is still attached to kernel, not process. So the process will not show up in that window.

Comment: well, I once managed to somehow change the `Processes and threads` window to show me notepad.exe in kernel debugger, but I don't remember how. So, it is possible. There's no real reason for why not to display the currently debugged process which i'm in context of.

Comment: But how to watch the stacktrace of any thread in another process (that is not currenty execute) in the kernel crashdump? If I switch context with '.process /p /r <addr>', the 'kb' command still returns stacktrace of the one where bugcheck happened.

Comment: @Rohan, that helped. Thank you!  I was also able to see the stacktrace with !process <process_address>  (it had the only thread).